# Correct way to perform Sql self union

Tags: sql-server

Let's say we have table as below:

```
table1:

**t1**   **t2**   **t3**
 abc       xyz      aaa
```

Can i do something like:

```
select * from(
(select t.t1,t.t2,t.t3 from table1 t) as tmp
union
(select tmp2.t1,'someothervalue' as t2,tmp2.t3 from tmp tmp2)) as result
order by result.t1
```

Basically union operation with the first tmp table itself. 
Let's say t1,t2,t3 all are of varchar type.

Comment: Yes, Union will work as long as the types being selected are implicitly compatible with each other. For example when you try a union between bigint and varchar, then you would get an error.

Answer (score 1):

`from tmp tmp2` is not possible instead of this you could use  `from table1 tmp2`, Updated Sql Query

```
SELECT * FROM(
     SELECT t.t1,t.t2,t.t3 FROM table1 t
UNION
     SELECT tmp2.t1,'someothervalue' as t2,tmp2.t3 FROM table1 tmp2
) as result
ORDER BY result.t1
```

Comment: -If suppose, in your query 't' is the result of some complex joins, in that case what could be done ?

Comment: It's the one in the question :)  Can't post my query here. But  the scenario is the same.

Comment: @KedarParikh this information is not enough,can't help out